# How to properly handle UI refresh after sync

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have an app that syncs data with the server on every launch with a Rails backend. The API fully works, but I'm having an issue with the interface becoming unresponsive when the interface needs to be refreshed.

I'm currently using GCD to start the sync:

```
Sync *sync = [[Sync alloc] init];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [sync force_sync:@""];
    [appModel updateSyncTime:current_time];
});
```

Once the sync is completed, I have the Sync object sending a NSNotification to the app so that the interface refreshes:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Sync-Completed" object:self];
});
```

When the notification is received, my other classes just simply reload the data in the UITableView, like so:

```
 - (void)notificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [dataTable reloadData];
 }
```

Up until the point the notification is received, the UI is completely responsive. Once the notification is received, you can't scroll UITableViews among other UI elements until the refresh is completed. I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously, the code that processes the notification is the issue.  Unfortunately, we have no idea what that does because you omitted that part.

Comment: Where in your code is the second piece of code sending out the notification, you say the sync is done - how do you know its done?

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Sync-Completed" object:self];
});
```

Is not Async - you just dumped a huge amount of refresh work on your main queue (the processing of the sync-completed notification)- so your app is going to lock up unless you address the code that updates the UI.

Also, using the global queue for a heavy IO operation is not necessarily a good idea.  I have seen cases where just doing that will lock up the UI - so make sure its the notification and not also the sync itself.

If you find it is the sync itself - create your own NSOperation queue and create an NSOperation out of that block.

Your mileage may vary but in general using the global queue has not worked for async IO for me.

Comment: You can also create dispatch queues.

Comment: true I just havent done that when global queues jam up my main thread I just create my own NSOperationQueue and fill it with ops...either way.